# Why the commit is not shown in the issue after it is closed as fixed?

Tags: community-official-site

Yesterday I saw that I forget to commit a change in a 8.x branch of a project, so I search for the commit message in the 7.x branch and I commit the changes and push my code to drupal.org, but today I see that the commit appears in the project page but not in the issue.

If you go to see the commit you will see the issue number and reference:

https://www.drupal.org/commitlog/commit/43654/082f754b0f3780979663afea014df3cb84d0eeec

> Issue [#2846726](https://www.drupal.org/node/2846726) by ...

But in the issue page the commit not appears, this can be because the issue have the *Closed (fixed)* status?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is more likely the case that the service that handles the issue updates was down for some period of time. Under normal circumstances pushing a commit to D.O. will update the issue referenced in the commit message no matter what the issue status is set to...

Comment: yes this is what I think too, is very rare.